# Has traffic in some hashtags "plunged" since Russia lost access to Twitter?

Tags: russia, twitter

[Russia has blocked access to Twitter and Facebook](https://www.theverge.com/2022/2/26/22952006/russia-block-twitter-ukraine-invasion-censorship-putin). Opinions vary as to why, but most speculate that it is to prevent the general public from knowing how the Ukraine invasion is going.
Today, I have seen a number of tweets that suggest this move has cut bots off as well as people. Here are three examples:

---

> https://twitter.com/zchamu/status/1498486656881643521
>
> [image: tweet]
>
> Text: Have you noticed that none of the anti-Trudeau hashtags have trended since Russia turned off Twitter? Huh.

Despite the ending of the occupation of Ottawa by the self-styled Freedom Convoy, these hashtags had persisted and I generally saw them in the Canada trending section until very recently.

---

> https://twitter.com/riamarismith/status/1498335636129992718
>
> [image: tweet]
>
> Text: This is a test tweet. Many are noticing dramatic ⬇️ in trolls/bots with restriction on Twitter in Russia. Here is my test. #Vaccines work. #CovidIsAirborne. #FreedomConvoy was shameful.   The #CPC supported insurrection. #Moe is ridiculous. Ok, if there is silence, we will know.

---

> https://twitter.com/nickmmark/status/1498672174055497729
>
> [image: tweet]
>
> Text: Seems like *most* of the COVID #misinformation is driven by Russian bots.
>
> When those bots get distracted by Russia’s #UkraineInvasion, all the interest in #myocarditis & #Ivermectin vanishes overnight.

---

Has there been a dramatic reduction in tweet volume (say in the last few days of February and today, the 1st of March) on particular hashtags?

Specifically, on anti-vaccine and anti-Trudeau hashtags? Is this related to lack of access from Russia?

(Conclusions about Russian bot farms may not be possible to draw, but I'm interested in information on that too.)

Comment: The title reads as if 'Russia' _has_ 'lost access'. Well, has it? What I read is that Twitter access was limited for Russian IPs — by the state of Russia itself?

Comment: For the first tweet, I believe the major protests in Canada were broken up last week so it doesn't seem surprising if Trudeau-related hashtags aren't trending as much anymore. For the second tweet, it seems to be talking about a reduction in "trolls/bots" rather than a reduction in hashtags, and is just using those hashtags to try to attract them? I don't think it's claiming what you're asking about, and I'm not sure an account with 1100 followers and a tweet with ~150 likes really reaches our notability requirements either.

Comment: Maybe the trolls found more juicy targets? Also correlation vs causation thing. (https://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations)

Comment: The x-axis on that graph does not say to me that this reduction was something that happened overnight, or even recently?

Comment: The Guardian suggests trhat bots have chnaged what they are attacking https://www.theguardian.com/media/2022/mar/04/bot-holiday-covid-misinformation-ukraine-social-media

Comment: @pinegulf I am interested in the conclusion "most of what was in those hashtags was bots/trolls and not people who cared about the issue." Whether the bot/trolls stopped posting anti-Trudeau stuff because they were in Russia and lost Twitter access, thus were never in Canada (thus don't care about internal policies as they claimed) or because they got new orders to cover the war, the conclusion would still hold.